# GPUAUX issue [AUX]GuiExtAuxCheckAuxPath LogCat

Tags: android, cordova, canvas, webview

Running a Cordova app (native app with a webview) in debug mode on my device (OPPO) in Android Studio, LogCat displays the following error:

`6960-6994  GPUAUX com.package.name E  [AUX]GuiExtAuxCheckAuxPath:674: Null anb`

It appears to happen whenever I change a CSS and/or DOM attribute and start using canvas operations involving images in RequestAnimationFrame. It's getting spammed on every frame so 60 times per sec, which raises the question whether its having some impact on performance. Does anyone know what this message means and whether it's safe to ignore, or have a solution on how to actually fix this or other helpful pointers or input?

Packages / libraries being used:

> Cordova android: 12.0.0
> Cordova: 10.0.0 to 12.0.0
> Gradle: 7.6
> Android Gradle
> Plugin (AGP): 7.4.2
> androidX webkit: 1.4 to 1.7

**EDIT:**
After updating cordova to latest (v12.0.0) and setting my project to use Webkit 1.7 (instead of cordova's default 1.4) through the project.properties file, its still giving this error at the same times as before: when I change stuff in the DOM or render-blocking CSS and canvas operations involving images.